# Can I specify and RSS item GUID or item offset with Mailchimp RSS merge tags?

Tags: email, drupal, web-applications, rss, mailchimp

I'm using the rss merge tags provided by mailchimp to get content from my drupal 6 sites' individual rss feeds into my mailchimp campgain and they work fine with the `*|FEEDBLOCK:URL* *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=3]|*....` syntax.

What I'm looking for is the ability to specify and offset or post GUID so that I can do some more involved layouts but still pull all the content in via RSS. I need to be able to display 2 posts from feed x starting from the most recent post, then have a custom image or text block, then show 2 more posts from feed x starting from the 3rd most recent post (an offset of two). I'd like to be able to interleave multiple feeds and show two items from feed x, two from feed y, 3 from feed z etc. and be able to show the next most recent item from feed x/y/z later on without repeating any items.

Is there a variable I can use with the feedblock merge tag like the $count variable, or is there a way that I can achieve this that I have missed in the docs? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the desire for GUID.  Can you explain why multiple feed blocks wouldn't work?  Each feedblock can have its own URL set, so you can use *|FEEDBLOCK:XURL|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|* [new line] *|FEEDBLOCK:YURL|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|*, etc.  You can even use a different $count variable for each and it'll work for just that feedblock too.

Comment: Multiple feed blocks would work yes, but if I were include a feed block like |FEEDBLOCK:XURL| once in a layout, and again with the same feed URL later in the later out, theres no way to stop it from repeating the same posts as the first time. What I wanted was for it to resume the second feed block where the 1st one left off. I have since been told by mailchimp support that this isn't possible, so I solved the problem with yahoo pipes - http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ - It's great for manipulating and RSS feed into a new feed with filters, rules, sorts etc.

Comment: ah gotcha.   yep yep, that wouldn't be possible with their merge tags.  interesting solution!